# Is it possible to run a validator node on a forked net?

Tags: hardhat, validators

As the question says - is it possible to fork mainnet with hardhat and run/setup a validator node on the fork? There are some things I'd like to try out before testing it on testnet (I don't even have enough ETH on a testnet so it would be easy on a fork).

It looks like the launchpad is somewhat centralized that's what made me question if it's even possible to become a validator on the fork.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to fork the Ethereum mainnet using Hardhat and set up a validator node on the fork for testing purposes on a [website](https://lacelebrite.fr/).

This allows experimentation before deploying on the testnet. The launchpad's centralization doesn't affect forking and running a validator locally.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure if you added the correct website though.